# IE 11, Move directory once downloads is finished

Tags: c#, python, download, internet-explorer-11, move

I would like to build a small program to automate some of my daily work.

What I need, is to move all files and subfolders from a specific directory to anoter directory, once all downloads in it are finished.

Does anyone knows how to help me? It must be on Internet Explorer 11.

Any help envolving Python or C# would be appreciated!

Comment: You can probably toss together something with https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx - For more I would have to see more of an attempt on your part with a question about a specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the shutil Python module to help you. This changes the directory of the targeted file.

```
shutil.move(".../Downloads/file.foo", "path/to/new/destination/for/file.foo")
```

os and glob modules can help you iterate through the download folder to get the correct file names.

You can also use

```
os.access("C:\Downloads\", os.W_OK)  # return True if we can write to this file
```

to ensure that the file has been fully downloaded before the script can run because files whilst being downloaded are locked by the OS.